# Can someone explain the function of colon here?

Tags: ruby, ternary-operator

Can someone explain what `:` does in this case?

```
def group_by_marks(marks, n)
    marks.group_by {|key, value| value <n ? "Failed" : "Passed"}
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a ternary condition. The colon says that if `value` is greater than or equal to `n`, use `"Passed"`.

```
value < n ? "Failed" : "Passed"
```

Equivalent to

```
if value < n then "Failed" else "Passed" end
```

Answer (score 2):

It's ternary operator. If `value < n` is true, then the return value of this block is `"Failed"`; if `value < n` is false, return `"Passed"`.

You can simply regard this colon as "either this or that".